# Creating a Power BI scatter graph with date on the y-axis and time on the x-axis

Tags: mysql, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

So I have a table with dates and times of when a person entered a room. I created a scatter graph in excel of all the points where an occupancy was recorded. It looks like this:[image: Excel Graph I created]

However, when trying to recreate this in Power BI, I cannot add the date field into the y-axis. Power BI just refuses to let me add it.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

The example of my table looks like this:

| Date | Time |
| --- | --- |
| 04/06/2023 | 15:43 |
| 04/06/2023 | 14:44 |
| 03/06/2023 | 23:26 |

I have tried to add the date field but nothing in Power BI allows me to do it